# .htaccess redirection of a subdomain to a domain, while keeping the links

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, dns, subdomain

I have this URL:

```
http://subdomain.maindomain.com
```

and all the links are already shared like this:

```
http://subdomain.maindomain.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=xxx
http://subdomain.maindomain.com/index.php?route=product/category&path=xxx
http://subdomain.maindomain.com/index.php?route=information/information&information_id=xxx
```

Now the subdomain is no longer in use, and all the content is transferred in the maindomain, so I want when someone clicks some of those links, the links to be opened like this:

```
http://maindomain.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=xxx
http://maindomain.com/index.php?route=product/category&path=xxx
http://maindomain.com/index.php?route=information/information&information_id=xxx
```

i.e. only the subdomain to be redirected to the domain, but the links to be left as they are. Any chance that this can be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your main domain and sub domain are on the same root folder you can use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.(maindomain\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,L]
```

Otherwise all you need is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^ http://maindomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,L]
```